# node systemctl for discord.js bot error EACCES

Tags: node.js, json, bots, gnu-screen, systemctl

I want to start my discord.js bot with a systemctl.
When I enter

```
[Unit]
Description=Bots by Tjum28
After=network-online.target
[Service]
User=pi
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/pi/Bots/bot.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this in my `.service` file the bot starts but when I send a message I get this error:

Before I send a message:

```
● bot.service - Bots by Tjum28
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bot.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-25 19:01:05 CET; 13s ago
 Main PID: 9627 (node)
    Tasks: 11 (limit: 2062)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bot.service
           └─9627 /usr/bin/node /home/pi/Bots/bot.js

Mar 25 19:01:05 Server systemd[1]: Started Bots by Tjum28.
Mar 25 19:01:10 Server node[9627]: Bot ist gestartet und einsatzbereit als T&M Transporte
```

After I send a message:

```
● bot.service - Bots by Tjum28
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bot.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-25 19:01:05 CET; 13s ago
 Main PID: 9627 (node)
    Tasks: 11 (limit: 2062)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bot.service
           └─9627 /usr/bin/node /home/pi/Bots/bot.js

Mar 25 19:01:05 Server systemd[1]: Started Bots by Tjum28.
Mar 25 19:01:10 Server node[9627]: Bot ist gestartet und einsatzbereit als T&M Transporte
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './xpfile.json'] {
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]:   errno: -13,
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]:   code: 'EACCES',
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]:   syscall: 'open',
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]:   path: './xpfile.json'
Mar 25 19:01:18 Server node[9627]: }
```

I use a rank system with a `.json` file.
I know that there is a problem with the `.json` file (`xpfile.json`) but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the import in my bot.js file

```
let xpfile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/home/pi/Bots/xpfile.json", "utf8"));
```

The result from `ls -l /home/pi/Bots/xpfile.json`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 7416 [...] /home/pi/Bots/xpfile.json
```

When I start the bot with `screen` all is fine.

Comment: The error message suggests that the `pi` user doesn't have the required permissions to the file. What are the permissions of the file `xpfile.json`? What's the output of `ls -l /home/pi/Bots/xpfile.json`? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66805261/edit) your question to include details.

Comment: I added the result.

Comment: Is there some other function that tries to read or require `./xpfile.json` instead of `/home/pi/Bots/xpfile.json`?

Comment: I don't know an other way :(